# Is it possible to interact with a running instance of QGIS from the command line?

Tags: qgis, clip, mac, command-line

I just started looking at QGIS on MacOSX. I installed the MacPorts package and found the executable:

```
/Applications/MacPorts/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS*
```

Unfortunately it appears that the command line interface can only launch a new QGIS instance and cannot interact with an already running instance. I hope that I'm mistaken. Is there some way to interact (e.g. open files) with a running QGIS instance via a command line interface?

Comment: I don't know about Mac but in windows it's possible using C++, just *extremely* difficult. You would IMO be better off using pyQGIS in an existing session to modify it's behavior rather than trying to leverage it by its handle.